# In Xamarin Android, how can we implement a carousel view?

Tags: xamarin.android, carousel

I am using xamarin android.
I have to display a horizontal scrollable list.
As I am a beginner to Xamarin Android, I am unable to find a proper solution.

I could not find a proper way yet.

Answer (score 0):

I make a demo and it has three parts.

First, I create a `Model` class to define my datatype.

```
 public class Photo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
```

Second, I create a `ViewModel` class to handle the data.

```
public class MyViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            Photos = new ObservableCollection<Photo>();
            Photos.Add(new Photo() { Name = "Name1", Details = "Details1", Location = "Location1" });
            Photos.Add(new Photo() { Name = "Name2", Details = "Details2", Location = "Location2" });
            Photos.Add(new Photo() { Name = "Name3", Details = "Details3", Location = "Location3" });

        }
    }
```

Third, I bind the `ViewModel` to the `MainPage` and present it by a `CarouselView`.

In the MainPage.xaml.cs file

```
  public MainPage()
        {
            this.BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
          
        }
```

In the MainPage.xaml file

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Photos}">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <StackLayout>
                 <Frame HasShadow="True"
                       BorderColor="DarkGray"
                       CornerRadius="5"
                       Margin="20"
                       HeightRequest="100"
                       WidthRequest="100"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                     <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Details}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
               
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

For more information you can refer to the [Xamarin.Forms CarouselView Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/layout).

Comment: Thanks but I am using Xamarin.Android not Xamarin.Forms

Comment: In Xamarin.Android you can use the [ViewPager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/view-pager/viewpager-and-fragments). You can refer to the article [How to Make Carouselview In Xamarin.Andriod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62442777/how-to-make-carouselview-in-xamarin-andriod). Hope this can help you.