# Creating a Carousel in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android, carousel, android-motionlayout

I am attempting to create a `androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Carousel` in Xamarin.Android. I have looked at the following:

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/motionlayout/carousel

However, this was not extremely useful because it is not in C# or for Xamarin.Android. I was also somewhat unsure what to do for the adapter, since `Carousel.Adapter` doesn't seem to exist, and `Carousel.IAdapter` requires implementing multiple methods other than the ones mentioned. I would like to be able to see a complete example or tutorial for Xamarin.Android. I have never used `MotionLayout` or `Carousel`, although I have used `RecyclerView` many times (`Carousel.Adapter` looked similar to `RecyclerView.Adapter`, just with different names). Does anybody know of any good examples or tutorials for `Carousel` in Xamarin.Android?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you can use `ViewPager` to achieve this function in Xamarin android. `ViewPager` is a layout manager that lets you implement gestural navigation. Gestural navigation allows the user to swipe left and right to step through pages of data.

For more information, you can check document: [Xamarin.Android ViewPager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/view-pager/).

And in Xamarin.Forms, you can use [Xamarin.Forms CarouselView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/) to achieve this function.

Comment: `ViewPager` (or the more updated `ViewPager2`) is for navigational purposes (switching between full pages, that is why it is not called ViewItemer), or scenarios where the user knows what to expect and intends to move in very small increments. I want to allow the user to see the next & previous items in the list. I cannot use `CarouselView` because I am using Xamarin.Android (not Xamarin.Forms).

Comment: You can refer to the article [How to Make Carouselview In Xamarin.Andriod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62442777/how-to-make-carouselview-in-xamarin-andriod). Hope it could help you.